# SSL Apache Proxy with hostname not working

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, ssl

We have decided to run a secure web proxy through apache. we assigned the server a domain name and then bought SSL certificate for that domain and then applied on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) with Apache/2.2.22.

When I ran the server the default site(HTTP) i.e. only with IP as virtualhost, the proxy worked fine.

Then I decided to do SSL for this proxy server, since SSL for IP address is not allowed, we chose a domain and therefore went ahead.

Also I enabled mod_rewrite, so that all HTTP requests go through SSL website

Here is my HTTP virtual host and  SSL virtual host configruation respectively,

```
<VirtualHost 12.12.12.12:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 104.12
    </Proxy>
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R]
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

SSL configuration

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     <VirtualHost  12.12.12.12:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.net
        ServerAlias www.example.net
        ProxyVia On
        ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:443/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        #ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyRequests On
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/ssl_proxy/example_net.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl_proxy/example.net.key
        SSLProxyVerify require
        SSLProxyVerifyDepth 10
        SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl_proxy/example.net.csr
        SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl_proxy/example_net.ca-bundle
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
        <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Allow from 104.12
        </Proxy>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>
       <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory> 
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I tried all the above possiblities options, but none worked. So whenever I access a website what I get error as

```
Hostname example.net provided via SNI and hostname yahoo.com provided via HTTP are different.
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thank You
Sai

Comment: Are example.net and yahoo.com the real names? It would help to have the exact error message.

Comment: yes, example.net is my hostname (example is not original name, but it is a publicly setup) and I tried to connect through example.net to yahoo by enabling https on example.net. I hope I'm clear

Comment: Please also add the URL you are using and the mod_rewrite rules and some more info of what you are trying to do. It seems as if you are setting up an HTTPS pass-through to yahoo and the two certificates are getting mixed up.

Comment: Please check the confgurations of both HTTP and HTTPS are given. However do you need my real URL? What I'm trying to do is to setup a Forward Proxy with HTTPS over which I need to access anything on Web like not only html pages, but also music and videos. This is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the request you send to the proxy when you get this error, HTTP or HTTPS? If it is HTTPS, the CONNECT method required is not implemented before Apache 2.2.24 if I remember correctly.
Also, could you increase the LogLevel and post the result?

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying is to do CONNECT. I'm on  Ubuntu 12.04 and using Apache 2.2.22. so Should I upgrade to Apache 2.2.24?

Comment: @harrymc and bonob I did the changes, but no effect, I get the same error "Hostname example.net provided via SNI and hostname yahoo.com provided via HTTP are different." ?, does this link have anything to do with this http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200512.mbox/%3C8C29B2F93BAE9047A906EF6D6F9C5D43FE00B5@exchange2k301.gaia.fr%3E or this http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/solving-the-apache-ssl-error-oops-no-rsa-or-dsa-server-certificate-found-for-www-somedomain-com0

Comment: I don't think these links are for the same problem. If you are doing something like connecting to `https:/example.net/page` and redirecting it to `https:/yahoo.com/page`, the browser will hand over the example.net credential, not knowing that it's talking to yahoo.com. The error message then only expresses the browser's amazement with the answer it got.

Comment: @harrymc What I'm trying to do is something like a public proxy (not open for all except our users) with https encryption enabled. Users just gives our proxy settings and we will connect the user to the site.

Comment: I actually would say that the issue is not from the CONNECT method, but to make sure you could try to access an http (not https) page through the SSL proxy. See if you get the same error or not. Also, don't forget to increase the LogLevel (be daring, go to `debug` level) and check the resulting log.

Comment: @bonob I enabled debug, it still gives me the same error, It did not add any addional information `Hostname example.net provided via SNI and hostname yahoo.com provided via HTTP are different`

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594604/connect-request-to-a-forward-http-proxy-over-an-ssl-connection
Someone suggests using SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. You can check my config file. :)

Comment: It's "on" in your post!

Comment: @bonob I tried both "on" and "Off"

Comment: One last thing you could try is to define the SSL virtual host as the first virtual host. For a reason that I still don't understand, I was unable to use my SSL proxy vhost when it was not the first. Beside that, I'm afraid I ran out of ideas :/

Comment: I am not an Apache specialist, and your config files are too complex. In your place I would simplify everything to the bare minimum and start building up again until reaching the problem. Here are some resources for minimal configs: [[1](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/396967#396967)], [[2](http://blog.strongbackconsulting.com/2010/08/setting-up-ssl-reverse-proxy-in-apache.html)], [[3](http://andriigrytsenko.net/2011/02/apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-https-server/)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I figured out is, it is not possible through apache. But modern servers like Nginx, Node.js support it via SPDY protocol, Here is the [link](http://www.igvita.com/2012/06/25/spdy-and-secure-proxy-support-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: I know you are answering your own question, but can you provide the key points in your answer and use the link as a reference. Links can quickly become outdated or removed making your answer pointless for those who find your answer following a similar issue.

Comment: mod_spdy was available on Apache at least since 2012...

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1298273) in Apache which caused this error due to a case-sensitive comparison of hostnames. It was fixed recently and a new build with the fix [is now available](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/2.2.22-1ubuntu1.6). In addition, you can have the certificate changed to all lowercase to be more compatible with convention (uppercase is rarely used).